Brother P750W label printer doesn't work receiving esc/p commands from java DocPrintJob
I'm trying to print with ESC/P commands used a label printer Brother P750W. I'm using P-touch Editor 5.4 the printer works well but, when I'm tried to make my own labels from Java code, the printer doesn't work, it's look like it's connect to the printer, but do nothing. What do I can try now?
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintException;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;

import org.zyx.common.cli.Command;
import org.zyx.common.cli.CommandException;

public class CommandVialLabelPrintBrotherTest implements Command {

    @Override
    public void execute() throws CommandException {
        try {
            // Your ESC/P command to print a label with barcode

            PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
            PrintService brotherPrinter = null;

            for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
                System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());

            }

            // Find Brother PT-P750W
            for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
                System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());
                if (printer.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Brother PT-P750W (Copy 1)")
                        || printer.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Brother PT-P750W")) {
                    brotherPrinter = printer;

                }
            }

            if (brotherPrinter == null) {
                System.out.println("Brother PT-P750W not found!");
                return;
            }

            // Open a stream to send raw data to the printer
            DocPrintJob job = brotherPrinter.createPrintJob();

            String escCommands = "\u001B@" + // ESC @ - Initialize printer
                    "\u001Bi r 12" + // ESC i r 12 - Set label width to 12mm (0.47")
                    "\u001Bi L" + // ESC i L - Start label layout
                    "\u001Bi S 24" + // ESC i S 24 - Set text size to 24 points
                    "Hello Printer" + // The text to print
                    "\u001Bi d 1" + // ESC i d 1 - Print the label
                    "\u001Bi Z"; // ESC i Z - Cut the label (optional)

            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(escCommands.getBytes(), flavor, null);

            // Print the document
            job.print(doc, null);
            System.out.println("Raw ESC/P data sent to printer!");

        } catch (PrintException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}


I would guess that the individual chars from the string are converted to 16-bit numbers that are sent to the printer. But ESC/P works with 8 bit "characters" so e.g. ESC @ should probably only be 2 bytes instead of 4.

Certainly going from string to 'binary' could be problematic in itself. I would try to write literal byte[] values. e.g. final static byte[] PRINT_LABEL = { (byte)0xB1, 'i', ' ', 'd', ' ', 1}; (assuming spaces are necessary). I have to say I'm not sure if you should be doing this in network streamed mode though through a streaming print service interface
